# object Object вместо html тега br

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Ситуация следующая, пишу приложение на функциональном компоненте React.js, в стейт забиваю значение текстового инпута, а после беру в этом стейте все его значения и вывожу в параграф в другой части страницы.

Проблема в том, что значения стейта выводятся друг за другом, в одну строку, а мне нужно оформить так, что бы они выстраивались в стоблик, для этой задачи мне подойдёт тег разрыва строки `<br/>`, но проблема в том, что когда я его прописываю, то в выводе я получаю тот же вывод в одну строку, но с разделителем [object Object]

Какие есть варианты решения ?

Добавление брейка пробовал сделать по-разному, но результат одинаковый, вот вариант с джойном в параграфе

```
<p>
    {state.join(<br />)}
</p>
```

вот вариант добавления брейка на этапе сетСтейта

```
setState([...input, input.value + <br/>])
```

В обоих случаях, в рендере вижу

```
Item 1[object Object]Item 2[object Object]Item 3
```

Вместо желаемого

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<br/>` тут считается элементом `jsx`, который и является объектом.

Вместо этого нужно было использовать строку

```
state.join('<br />')
```

Результатом будет `html` строка, поэтому для ее вывода нужно воспользоваться либо специальными средствами, типа [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) либо отдельными библиотеками для вывода html в реакте.

Так же можно было использовать `.map`

```
state.map(el => <>{el}<br/></>)
```

Comment: Вариант со строкой не сработал, т.к. <br /> буквально отобразился как строка, а вот вариант с map сработал как нужно, благодарю, помогаете мне уже не в первый раз